# Function pointer difficulty in C, int (*foo(enum int var))(int)

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting

Looking at some OSCORE code here: https://github.com/Fraunhofer-AISEC/uoscore-uedhoc/blob/main/modules/oscore/src/option.c and at lines 31 and 63 there is some unusual casting and pointer function work I could use help with.

```
bool (*class_to_condition(enum option_class class))(uint16_t code)
{
    switch (class) {
    case CLASS_I:
        return is_class_i;       //is_class_x() returns bool
    case CLASS_E:
        return is_class_e;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and later

```
bool (*condition)(uint16_t) = class_to_condition(class);
```

then used as

```
if (!condition(code)) {
```

I get:

- class_to_condition(u16) will return a bool
- "condition" variable is a pointer to a the function class_to_condition, and this function will accept one argument
- uint16_t is the argument type the function accepts

I don't get

- the enum
- why it appears to take two arguments (sort of)
- Why is the function definition a pointer it self
- uint16_t "code" is never used in the class_to_condition() ?

Is this so much more efficient as a pointer over the obvious non-pointer alternative that it's worth the increased complexity (clever vs cute)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class_to_condition` function takes one argument of type `enum option_class`. It returns a pointer to a function which takes one `uint16_t` argument and returns a `bool`.

Using type-aliases would make it much clearer:

```
// Declare a -alias of a function pointer
typedef bool (*condition_function_type)(uint16_t);

condition_function_type class_to_condition(enum option_class class)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

condition_function_type condition = class_to_condition(class);
```

---

[The clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) could be helpful in decipher complex declarations.

Comment: Selected this as the answer because it includes a teach a man to fish link…. Using the clockwise spiral rule: “class_to_condition is a function that accepts an enum and returns a pointer to a function that accepts a uint16 returning a bool”… that’s very helpful, thanks!  

I’m still skeptical this is worth the complexity in this exact case. - As to returning false in the default case, this would make *condition into NULL(uint16_t) and then line 69 is checking if pointer is not null OR if *func evals true/false? 

Ok, that seems clever. Although I would have returned NULL over false.

Answer (score 5):

The function `class_to_condition` takes an `enum option_class` as an argument and returns a function pointer.  The function pointer being returned points to a function that has a `uint16_t` argument and returns a `bool`.

If we added the following typedef:

```
typedef bool (*fptr)(uint16_t);
```

We could rewrite the function signature as:

```
fptr class_to_condition(enum option_class class) {
```

And the call as:

```
fptr condition = class_to_condition(class);
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the @Someprogrammerdude answer, I would not personally hide the pointer behind the `typedef`

```
typedef bool condition_function_type(uint16_t);

condition_function_type *class_to_condition(enum option_class class)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

condition_function_type *condition = class_to_condition(class);
```

IMO it is much easier to read and understand that we are dealing with function pointers.

Comment: *I would not personally hide the pointer behind the `typedef`*??  Did you mean the opposite of that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Not hiding is opposite to hiding. Isn't it? To be honest I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I thought you were referring to the function pointer itself.